# Python Pandas: Count quarterly occurrence from start and end date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of jobs for different people with star and end time for each job. I'd like to count, every four months, how many jobs each person is responsible for. I figured out away to do it but I'm sure it's tremendously inefficient (I'm new to pandas). It takes quite a while to compute when I run the code on my complete dataset (hundreds of persons and jobs).

Here is what I have so far.

```
#create a data frame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'job': pd.Categorical(['job1','job2','job3','job4']),
               'person': pd.Categorical(['p1', 'p1', 'p2','p2']),
               'start': ['2015-01-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-01-01', '2016- 01- 01'],
               'end': ['2015-07-01', '2015- 12-31', '2016-03-01', '2016-12-31']})
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
```

Which gives me

[image]

I then create a new dataset with

```
bdate = min(df['start'])
edate = max(df['end'])
dates = pd.date_range(bdate, edate, freq='4MS')

people = sorted(set(list(df['person'])))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(dates), len(people))), index=dates, columns=people)

for d in pd.date_range(bdate, edate, freq='MS'):
    for p in people:
        contagem = df[(df['person'] == p) &
           (df['start'] <= d) &
           (df['end'] >= d)]
        pos = np.argmin(np.abs(dates - d))
        df2.iloc[pos][p] = len(contagem.index)

df2
```

And I get

[image]

I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this without having to loop through all dates and persons. But how?

Comment: Your question states that you want your output to be quarterly, but your example code and output is done triannually.  Which one do you want?

Comment: Meant every 4 months. Fixed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that each job-person combination is unique. It creates a series for every row with the value equal to the job an index that expands the dates. Then it resamples every 4th month (which is not quarterly but what your solution describes) and counts the unique non-na occurrences.

```
def make_date_range(x):
    return pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(x.start.values[0], x.end.values[0], freq='M'), data=x.job.values[0])

# Iterate through each job person combo and make an entry for each month with the job as the value
df1 = df.groupby(['job', 'person']).apply(make_date_range).unstack('person')

# remove outer level from index
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel('job')

# resample each month counting only unique values
df1.resample('4MS').agg(lambda x: len(x[x.notnull()].unique()))
```

Output

```
person      p1  p2
2015-01-01   1   1
2015-05-01   2   1
2015-09-01   1   1
2016-01-01   0   2
2016-05-01   0   1
2016-09-01   0   1
```

And here is a long one line solution that iterates over every rows and creates a new dataframe and stacks all of them together via `pd.concat` and then resamples.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(tup.start, tup.end, freq='4MS'), 
                        data=[[tup.job]], 
                        columns=[tup.person])  for tup in df.itertuples()])\
  .resample('4MS').count()
```

And another one that is faster

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['job', 'person'], value_name='date').set_index('date')

g = df1.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('4MS'), 'person'])['job']

g.agg('nunique').unstack('person', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick to the first solution, which is a bit easier for me to read. It will take a while for me to understand what every step is doing but I'll figure it out, eventually. Meanwhile, the third solution is not giving the same answer as the first two.

Comment: I don't think the third version is correct. `date` isn't one of the columns - it needs to calculate whether the indexed month falls between `start` and `end`.