# Counting number of items active in each month, calculated from per-item start and end dates in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

Suppose we have the following `DataFrame`, which details bugs in a bug tracking system:

```
import pandas as pd

bugs = pd.DataFrame([
    {'key': 'ABC-1', 'priority': 'high', 'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 1), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,3,20)},
    {'key': 'ABC-2', 'priority': 'med',  'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 2), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,1,20)},
    {'key': 'ABC-3', 'priority': 'high', 'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 3), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,3,20)},
    {'key': 'ABC-4', 'priority': 'med',  'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 4), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,3,20)},
    {'key': 'ABC-5', 'priority': 'high', 'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 5), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,2,20)},
    {'key': 'ABC-6', 'priority': 'med',  'start': pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 6), 'end': pd.Timestamp(2018,3,20)}
], columns=['key', 'priority', 'start', 'end'])
```

Here, `start`, and `end` represent the date a bug was first found, and the date it was closed.

How can we calculate the number of "open" bugs by month, broken down by priority? That is, an output that looks like:

```
           High   Med
Month
January       1   2
February      3   1
March         2   2
```

The challenge is to take account of both "start" and "end" date. So, a bug of priority "high" that was opened on January 5th and closed on February 3rd should be counted towards the "high" priority bugs for January and February, but not March. And so on.

Comment: would two bugs with same priority, happening in same months but different years, end up as being counted the same ?

Comment: no, the idea is "per calendar month", not "any January"

Answer (score 1):

I am using `stack` with `resample`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

s=bugs.set_index(['key','priority']).stack() # faltten your dataframe , make start and end in the same row , since we do need a range of date
s=pd.to_datetime(s)+MonthEnd(1) # change the date to same scale , month end , since you need monthly data only 
s=s.reset_index().drop_duplicates(['key',0]) # if the start is same with end , we only need keep one of them. 

s=s.groupby('key').apply(lambda x : x.set_index(0).resample('M').ffill()).reset_index(level=1)    # groupby the key then we resample , adding the value between the start and end prepare for the frequency count  

pd.crosstab(s[0].dt.month,s['priority'])# count the frequency 
Out[149]: 
priority  high  med
0                  
1            1    2
2            3    1
3            2    2
```

Comment: Would love an explanation of what's going on here. Even stepping through it, it does a lot of ... stuff. :-) Seems to work in my tests, though!

Comment: @optilude adding the explanation line by line :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple and short :)
The idea is to select, per month, the rows whose bug overlap each month.

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 
          'April']  # of course  you can complete this list

bugs[months] = pd.concat([((bugs['start'].dt.month <= i) & 
                           (i <= bugs['end'].dt.month)).astype(int) 
                          for i in range(1, len(months) + 1)], axis=1)

bugs.groupby('priority')[months].sum()
```

Result :

```
          January  February  March  April
priority                                 
high            1         3      2      0
med             2         1      2      0
```

Comment: This requires me to predefine the months, and counts the same month in two different years as the same category. Maybe I didn't explain the question very well, but that's not quite right. The idea is to show a historical trend, e.g. "10 high priority defects were open last month, up from 5 that were open the month before".

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

# Last day of the previous month
bugs['start1'] = bugs.start + MonthEnd(-1)

# The first days of the months that > start1 and <= end
bugs['months']  = bugs[['start1', 'end']].apply(lambda x: tuple(pd.date_range(x[0], x[1], freq='MS')), axis=1, raw=True)

# Create dummy columns
dummies = bugs.months.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({k:1 for k in x})).fillna(0)
bugs = bugs.join(dummies)

# Aggregation
bugs.groupby('priority')[dummies.columns].sum().T


priority    high  med
2018-01-01   1.0  2.0
2018-02-01   3.0  1.0
2018-03-01   2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229174/python-pandas-count-quarterly-occurrence-from-start-and-end-date-range) I managed to make the following work:

```
def strip_day(timestamp):
    return pd.Timestamp(timestamp.year, timestamp.month, 1)

monthly_bugs = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(strip_day(b.start), strip_day(b.end), freq='MS'), data=[[b.key]], columns=[b.priority])
    for b in bugs.itertuples()
]).resample('MS').count()
```

I'm not sure if it's better than some of the other answers posted here, though (thanks!).